# Rinex Header GPS Position Coordinate System

Tags: gps, pyproj, rinex

I am extracting data from rinex observation files and would like to convert the approximate position to latitude and longitude using Proj.4. The [rinex standard](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/RINEX211.txt) states that these coordinates are WGS84, which I assume refers to the ellipsoid. What are the Proj4 parameters I need to do the conversion? If this is not possible is there another route I can take? Specifically I'm using the pyproj Python library. The correct coordinates should be close to (45.4343,-123.5516).

I am using [RTKLib](http://www.rtklib.com/) to process the observations, but want to automate downloading the base station/CORS files.

I did just find this [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56730-gps-receiver-position?focused=6227610&tab=function) that performs the conversion. I've ported it to Python and it works well for my needs. Still if there is a way to get Proj4 to do this that would be ideal as I use that library for other projects.

Here is the Python I've tested:

```
In [29]: prj = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent',ellps='WGS84',datum='WGS84')

In [30]: prj(-2478053.2006,-3736604.9657)
Out[30]: (1e+30, 1e+30)

In [31]: prj(-2478053.2006,-3736604.9657,inverse=True)
Out[31]: (-22.260730649602785, -33.5664935140521)
```

Here is an example header.

```
     2.00           OBSERVATION DATA    M (MIXED)           RINEX VERSION / TYPE
                                        20180413 230424 UTC PGM / RUN BY / DATE 
28jxmqr6                                                    MARKER NAME         
                                                            MARKER NUMBER       
                    off                                     OBSERVER / AGENCY   
100037              BE-GPS-3300         2.1.47              REC # / TYPE / VERS 
                                                            ANT # / TYPE        
 -2478053.2006 -3736604.9657  4521684.4805                  APPROX POSITION XYZ 
        0.0000        0.0000        0.0000                  ANTENNA: DELTA H/E/N
     1     1                                                WAVELENGTH FACT L1/2
     4    C1    L1    C2    L2                              # / TYPES OF OBSERV 
  2018     4    13    19     8   50.5000000     GPS         TIME OF FIRST OBS   
  2018     4    13    19    23   28.0000000     GPS         TIME OF LAST OBS    
                                                            END OF HEADER
```

Comment: You have to use all 3 numbers, not 2.

Comment: Yes, that was the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geocentric coordinates can be converted to latitude, longitude, and altitude by using the `pyproj.transform` function. The `Proj.__call__` method does not accept Z values, which are required for the transformation.

```
In [6]: p1 = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent',ellps='WGS84',datum='WGS84',units='m',no_defs=True)

In [7]: p2 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')

In [8]: pyproj.transform(p1,p2,-2478053.2006,-3736604.9657,4521684.4805)
Out[8]: (-123.55166435788638, 45.43449642806122, 450.48841851670295)
```

The output is equivalent to the following cs2cs input:

```
cs2cs +proj=geocent +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +units=m +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%.8f"
-2478053.2006 -3736604.9657  4521684.4805
-123.55166436   45.43449643 450.48841852
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a normal projection library is going to do the conversion for you.

While these coordinates are WGS84, they are cartesian (XYZ) coordinates, and not geodetic (Lat/Lon).

This [forum post](https://www.gps-forums.com/threads/program-to-convert-from-to-wgs-xyz-lat-long-rinex-s-w.29581/) says that you can use the program [GeoConv](http://www.kolumbus.fi/eino.uikkanen/geoconvgb/index.htm) to do the conversion.

Maybe you should have a look at the [RTKLib](https://github.com/ruffsl/RTKLIB-Tools/wiki/Setup) and see if it can proces the file for you?

Comment: If you know the axis directions, handedness, and orientation you can use trigonometry to work out the direction, and that gives you the lat-long. Probably the X axis goes through Null Island (lat=0, long=0) and the Y axis through (lat=0, long=plus or minus 90). The Z axis probably goes through the north pole....

Comment: I think PROJ.4 has a "+proj=geocent" option now. See [this issue](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/16) which shows a cs2cs example.

Comment: The math is listed here, actually: https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/equations-used-datum

Comment: @Spacedman 3D Cartesian to lat/lon/h on an ellipsoid generally requires iteration.

Comment: @mkennedy I am using the `geocent` option. I'll try the cs2cs example to see if that works.

Comment: @mkennedy pretty sure intersection of a line with an ellipse has a simple closed form. That should be sufficient - work out the intersection point then the geodetic latitude is the normal to the ellipse at that point.

Comment: @Spacedman the vector often does not end at the surface. I work at esri. Our library's function is iterative. If there was a reasonable closed form, we'd use it.

Comment: If I have a cartesian x,y,z based on an earth origin, the intersection of the line passing through (0,0,0) (x,y,z) with an ellipsoid centred at (0,0,0) of known major/minor axis oriented with the Z axis has a closed form. I'll draw some diagrams if I get a chance and post a question, its on-topic here I reckon... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse-LineIntersection.html

Comment: @Spacedman I found a non-iterative on [mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/geocentrictogeodeticlatitude.html) for converting geocentric latitude to geodetic, but the same site uses Bowring (iterative) to convert [ECEF to LLA](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/ecefpositiontolla.html).